# Why does the compiler say 'Illegal use of floating point'?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'm a beginner level programmer. I wrote the following code to calculate area of sphere by storing area and radius in arrays.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define PI 3.1415

float findArea(float radius);

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    float radius[50], area[50];
    int i=0;
    cout<<"Enter radius of football, 0 to quit ";
    cin>>radius[i];
    area=findArea(radius[i]); //Compiler indicates error in this line
    cout<<area;

    while (radius[i]!=0)
    {
    ++i;
    cout<<"\nEnter the  radius of football, press 0 to quit ";
    cin>>radius[i];
    area=findArea(radius[i]); //And in this line
    cout<<area[i];
    }
    getch();
}

float findArea(float radius)
{
    return 4 * PI * radius * radius;
}
```

The error I get is 'Illegal use of floating point'. What's wrong with my code. Help please.

Comment: Yeah, I did it Ken. This was my first question in this forum. So, didn't know much about posting.

Comment: That's much better on both counts. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
area=findArea(radius[i]);
```

`area` is an array - perhaps `area[i]` is what you want

Comment: @Sparsh - perhaps a tick will not go amiss